# Merging 2 binary files. Residual data between files

Tags: c, file, merge, binary, concatenation

My assignment is to merge multiple binary files, and then put all of it in a txt file, I already have the format of the files, I`ve already wrote them, but I fail on merging them. This is the function:
[Output from the binary file into the txt file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew3p1.png)

```
int merge_files()
{
    FILE *f1, *ft;
    char ch, name1[20];
    int  error, n;
    char buffer[10000];
    printf("\n Give name of file: "); gets_s(name1, 19);
    while (strlen(name1) != NULL)
    {
        fopen_s(&f1, name1, "rb");
        fopen_s(&ft, "finaldata.dat", "a");
        if (!f1)
        {
            error = 1;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            error = 0;

            rewind(f1);

            while (n = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 10000, f1))
            {
                fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), n, ft);
                fflush(ft);
            }
        }

        fclose(f1);
        fclose(ft);
        printf("Files had been merged");
        printf("\n Give name of file: "); gets_s(name1, 19);
    }

    return error;
}
```

Comment: My bad then, it just looks totally wrong... I'll have to check the MS versions more closely.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It does not work, I use Visual Studio 2013, FILE* is not compatible with parameter of type FILE**

Comment: I told you wrong -- I apologize. I presumed `fopen` and `fopen_s` took the same parameters. I don't use MS, so I was surprised when whozcraig pointed out the `fopen_s` did in fact want a *pointer-to-pointer-to-FILE*. Revert to your original...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  'fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 10000, f1)' I copied it from what i posted here, I dont really understand that '..sizeof(char), 10000..' , It does not appear in my code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not coherent:

```
fopen_s(&f1, name1, "rb");
fopen_s(&ft, "finaldata.dat", "a");
```

Depending on your operating system it could not work. Default mode is text mode, so you open source file in binary mode and target file in text mode. If your OS is windows, you will get supplementary characters. Just do this way:

```
fopen_s(&f1, name1, "rb");
fopen_s(&ft, "finaldata.dat", "ab"); // both files in binary mode
```

Edit: check there is no utf-8 BOM in your entry files with the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BOM_SIZE 3

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int err = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        FILE *f = fopen (argv[i], "r");
        if (f != NULL) {
            unsigned char buf[BOM_SIZE];
            if (fread(buf, sizeof(char), BOM_SIZE, f) == BOM_SIZE)
            {
                printf("File %s starts with:\n", argv[1]);

                for (int j = 0; j < BOM_SIZE; j++)
                {
                    printf("0x%02x%s", (unsigned int) buf[j], (j < BOM_SIZE - 1) ? ", " : "\n");
                }
            }
            else if (ferror(f))
            {
                perror("fread");
                fprintf(stderr, "Error reading file %s\n.", argv[1]);
                err = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("File %s is too short to have a UTF-8 BOM.\n", argv[1]);
            }
            fclose(f);
        }
        else
        {
            perror("fopen");
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", argv[i]);
            err = 1;
        }
    }

    return err;
}
```

If any file starts with sequence "0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf" then you have a utf-8 bom!

Comment: Still not working, it still adds supplementary characters.

Comment: @sNow11 Could you provide simple files with which you get your bug? I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: It seems that this is a pretty delicate problem, anything I would do, any function, it adds characters after each merged file. Idk why. 
By the way, I changed the function completly and still not working. I will post the answer here if I manage to find it. Thanks forthe answers!

Comment: @sNow11 Why do you refuse to transmit those files? Do you know what is a UTF-8 BOM? I am adding code in my answer to check the three first characters in a file.